# how to format html helpers in webgrid column

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

```
var grid = new WebGrid(Model, rowsPerPage: 10, canPage: true);

 @grid.GetHtml(
       columns: new[]
       {
       grid.Column("CompanyName",
                    style: "col1",
                    format:@Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => modelItem.CompanyName,new{@class="edit-mode"})
    )
})
```

at format its showing like this

`cannot convert from html string to function <dynamic object>`

I have also tried

```
format: item => Html.TextBox(
        (string)item.CompanyName
    )
```

how do i format html helpers in webgrid ?

Answer (score 2):

Try like this:

```
grid.Column(
    "CompanyName",
    style: "col1",
    format: item => Html.TextBoxFor(
        modelItem => modelItem.CompanyName, 
        new { @class="edit-mode" }
    )
)
```

But I guess that's not what you want, because I guess that your view is bound to a different model.

What you need instead is the following:

```
grid.Column(
    "CompanyName",
    style: "col1",
    format: 
        @<text>
            @{ var index = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(); }
            @Html.Hidden("HeaderItems.Index", index)
            Html.TextBox(
                "[" + index + "].CompanyName", 
                item.CompanyName, 
                new { @class="edit-mode" }
            )
        </text>
)
```

and now the view you will be posting to could be strongly typed to a collection of your view model:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SomeAction(IEnumerable<CompanyViewModel> model)
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it would be like:

```
Format: m => Html.TextBoxFor(mdelItem => modelItem.CompanyName, new {@class="edit-mode"})
```